# Notification without using firebase console

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm a newbie in Android, I have created a program which will send notification using firebase without using firebase console.I have used php as backend what happeing is I'm getting notification only when send through firebase console, but when I send it through wamp server I can't.though I'm getting success:1

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nUSoCZlnDo

Comment: which type of backend technology you are using for server.

Comment: I am using java here though I have used php as well but couldn't get my output.

Comment: @Raghunandan the link you shared it is of no use.

Comment: it gives you a hint of what you should do. the video does not give you any code assistance..

Comment: @Raghunandan I'm not using firebase database.

Comment: you need some mechanism which observers data base changes in your server and then communicate what needs to be pushed to the firebase cloud. that in turn pushes messages to all registered devices.

Comment: @Raghunandan my priority is to send notification without open firebase console

Comment: you need not read my comment again

Comment: @Anil can you please help me with this

Comment: You should have a look at [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) :)

Comment: @jerry Sorry for late response

Comment: You can send it with Postman or something like that.
Here's the example - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55333788/7130820

Answer (score 0):

You can send notification by using following php code from your server

```
function sendNotification($fields = array())
{
$API_ACCESS_KEY = 'YOUR KEY';
$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . $API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
return $result;
}
$title = 'Whatever';
$message = 'Lorem ipsum';
$fields = array
(
'registration_ids'  => ['deviceID'],
'data'          => '',
'priority' => 'high',
'notification' => array(
    'body' => $message,
    'title' => $title,
    'sound' => 'default',
    'icon' => 'icon'
    )
    );
   sendNotification($fields);
```

Comment: hey! i followed Ravi tamada tutorial for the same.he used php for backend.when I run that I get Success:1 but couldn't get the notification.Any help!?

Answer (score 0):

You can use push notifications which you can setup using Nodejs by following the tutorials here:

https://youtu.be/8TGIMLdcl9E

It's the best way but it incorporates firebase functions and cloud messaging.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Call this function in your controller:

```
function sendPushNotification($title, $message, $id = null)
{
    $condition = "!('anytopicyoudontwanttouse' in topics)";

    $url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
    $header = [
        'authorization: key= AAAAoF8nm7A:APA91bG1*********', //server key
        'content-type: application/json'
    ];

    $postdata = '{
        "notification" : {
                "title":"' . $title . '",
                "text" : "' . $message . '"
            },
        "data" : {
            "id" : "' . $id . '",
            "title":"' . $title . '",
            "description" : "' . $message . '",
            "text" : "' . $message . '",
            "is_read": 0
          },
          "condition": "' . $condition . '"
    }';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}
```

You will notice there is no `to:` in this code. Instead I have used a condition which allows to send notifications to all devices (not for a particular topic) without providing tokens. If you need to send to particular devices, just add like this `"to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",`